# ExtJS - Load store with params

Tags: extjs, parameters, load, store, extjs3

I'm trying to load store with params in order to filter my data (as "where" in SQL) however I didn't find how to do that ...
Therefore, I made a filter on store load in order to make this but when there are many data, lags appears because it load all data and then filter them.

Is it possible to load store with params ? I tried for example :

```
store.load({
     params: { id : '300'},
});
```

But it's not working ..

Here is my code;
(I'm using ExtJS3.4 in a GroupOffice module (MVC model) that's why you can see "GO.", ... ).

I declare my store

```
GO.gestionfrais.storeAffichageMesFrais = new GO.data.JsonStore({                
url: GO.url('gestionfrais/frais/store'), // URL to my model
                fields: ['id',...], 
//              method: 'POST', // Have I to write this line ?
//              read: 'POST',
                model: 'GO\\Gestionfrais\\Model\\Frais',
        });
```

Then I created my filter:

```
GO.gestionfrais.storeAffichageMesFrais.on('load', function(){
     GO.gestionfrais.storeAffichageMesFrais.filterBy( function(record, id) { 
          if(record.get("id_user") == id_currentUser && record.get('archive') == 'Non' ) { 
               return true;
          }
          return false;
     }, this);
});
```

And finally I load my store

```
GO.gestionfrais.storeAffichageMesFrais.load( /*{params ?}*/ );
```

Thanks for reading me.

### EDIT 1:

I have modify the Store declaration by following mindparse link :

```
GO.gestionfrais.storeAffichageMesFrais = new GO.data.JsonStore({
        // store configs
        autoDestroy: true,
        url: GO.url('gestionfrais/frais/store'),
        storeId: 'storeAffichageMesFrais',
        // reader configs
        root: 'results',
        idProperty: 'results',
        fields: ['id', 'id_user', 'user', 'id_resp','demandeur', 'mois', 'prixTotal', {name: 'dateCreation', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'd-m-Y'}, 'etat', {name: 'dateSoumission', type: 'date', dateFormat:'d-m-Y'}, 'archive', {name: 'dateValidation', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'd-m-Y'}], // On récupère les champs qui nous intéressent (soit ceux à afficher).
        //Added
        model: 'GO\\Gestionfrais\\Model\\Frais',
});
```

Then I tried to load store with params (id=320) and I can see this in the header :

> Query String Parameter
> --> r:gestionfrais/frais/store
> --> security_token:ITy...
>
> Form Data
> --> id:320
> --> sort:id
> --> dir:ASC
> --> security_token:ITyc ....

My param isn't in "Query String Parameters", is it normal ?

Comment: Your store definition looks odd, compare to the docs http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/?mobile=/api/Ext.data.JsonStore I can't see any root property set for example

Comment: Thanks for you quick answer @mindparse.

I made the same example I've seen in your link but my params still doesn't work .. 
When I look at the Header of the file I can see that my URL and a securityToken are in "Query String Parameters" and my param (an id) is in "Form data" with the sort (reader ?) .

Answer (score 2):

Use proxy configuration to send extra params to your controller :

```
store.proxy.extraParams = { id1 : '300', id2: '22', ... };
store.load();
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. However it doesn't work .. I tried it with my store in my "Edit 1" and I put this code :
`GO.gestionfrais.storeAffichageMesFrais.proxy.extraParams = { id : '2' };
GO.gestionfrais.storeAffichageMesFrais.load();`

But my store isn't loaded with params. As I said in my "EDIT 1", with 'params' it's loading in Form data while with 'proxy.extraParams' I can't see my id in the Http Header ...